# list of sub-lists provided number of sublists and its elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def listOfLists(ntimes,lines,list_val):
    a = []
    i = 0
    j = 0

    if ntimes >= lines:
        inner_loop = ntimes
        outer_loop = lines
    else:
        inner_loop = lines
        outer_loop = ntimes

    while i < outer_loop:
        while j < inner_loop+i:
            if (j*inner_loop-i < len(list_val)):
                a.append(list_val[j*inner_loop-i])
                j=j+1

            else:
                j=1
                a.append(list_val[j*inner_loop-i])
                break

        j = i+1
        i = i+1
        print a
    y = [a[x:x+ntimes] for x in range(0, len(a), ntimes)]
    print y
```

What I'd like is a list with sublists whose number of elements is ntimes and lines is the number of sublists. If input is like `listOfLists(2,3,[1,2,3,4,5,6])` then output should be:

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

I'm currently getting:

```
[[1, 4], [4, 3], [6, 3]]
```

How can I fix my code to achieve this?

Comment: The function has one tricky feature, first two numbers must add by multiplication length of last list.

Comment: and distance between them is two

Comment: The answers from both @wim and I ignore the `ntimes` argument, and would return `[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]` for `listOfLists(2,3,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`. What is supposed to happen if `ntimes` times `lines` is not equal to `len(list_val)`?

Comment: list contain ntimes*lines number of elements that's why can't ignore ntimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def listOfLists(ntimes, lines, list_val):
    return zip(*zip(*(iter(list_val),) * lines))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`grouper` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(*grouper(L, 3))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The zip gives you tuples inside.  If you need lists for some reason, transform with a comprehension:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in _]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works if the length of `lst` is multiplication of `lines`

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> lines = 3
>>> zip(*zip(*[iter(lst)]*lines))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

This magic is derived from `grouper` mentioned by wim.

## Explaining the magic

Have a list of values

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Create an iterator over list values:

```
>>> iter(lst)
<listiterator at 0x7f641480d490>
```

Note: iterator is able to yield item by item from itself, in this case it is ready to yield item by item from the `lst`

Create list containing one iterator:

```
>>> [iter(lst)]
[<listiterator at 0x7f641480d750>]
```

The list is mutable structure, so even when referenced from multiple variables, it still refers to
the same data structure in memory. If any of these refernces uses the iterator inside, the iterator
is modified for all the references to this list.

Now create multiplication of the list, multiplying by number of expected lines.

```
>>> [iter(lst)] * 3
[<listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>,
 <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>,
 <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>]
```

Note, that all the iterators are showing the same address, all three items in this list are refering
to the same iterator.

Now the filan step, zipping it all togather:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(lst)] * 3)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

It could be rewritten as:

```
zip(*[<listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>, <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>, <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>])
```

what translates (via dereferencing by `*`) to:

```
>>> zip(<listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>, <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>, <listiterator at 0x7f641480dc50>)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

The `zip` works in the way, it asks each of the iterators to provide one value and creates a tuple
from these 3 values. The trick is, that each request for a value from the iterator consumes it from
all the references, so next time it asks any of iterators, next value will come.

The final step is doing final zipping:

```
zip(*[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
```

translates to:

```
zip((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

and we have the result:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```